# How is this value calculated?

Tags: c

```
#define     no          14022014L

unsigned long Pack(unsigned long num){
    unsigned long tmp;
    unsigned char *s=NULL;
    int k = 0;
    int sz_long = sizeof(unsigned long); 
    if (num ) {
        tmp=0L;
        s = (unsigned char *) &tmp;
        while(sz_long){
            k=(--sz_long)<<3;
            printf("k = %d\n", k);
            k=(int)(num >> k );
            printf("k=num >> k=%d\n", k);
            k=k & 0xFF;
            printf("k=k & 0xFF=%d\n", k);
            *s++ = (unsigned char) k;
            printf("tmp = %lu\n", tmp);
        }
        return tmp;
    }
    return num;
}


int main(void){
    unsigned long t;
    t=Pack(no);
    if ( t) {
        printf("t = %lu\n", t);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

### Output

```
Pack
k = 24
k=num >> k=0
k=k & 0xFF=0
tmp = 0
k = 16
k=num >> k=213
k=k & 0xFF=213
tmp = 54528              // how ?
k = 8
k=num >> k=54773
k=k & 0xFF=245
tmp = 16110848            // how ?
k = 0
k=num >> k=14022014
k=k & 0xFF=126
tmp = 2130040064          // how ?

Main()
t = 2130040064
```

Q: How the value to tmp calculated ?

Comment: `*s++ = (unsigned char) k1` s pointes to each byte in temp. and its altered from there.

Comment: why it is altering as in function nothing such thing is provided. same results on multiple compilers also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm builds a long value a byte at a time. If you change all you formats to hexadecimal you should be able to see the number being built up more clearly.

Comment: Ok. But How is possible as input is of 8 digits but output is of 10 digits even I change to Hexadecimal no way to found how it is calc.

Comment: @Vineet1982 The output (7E F5 D5 00) is greater than the input (00 D5 F5 7E). It's not strange that it has more digits. (Printing in hex doesn't print the leading zeroes.)

Answer (score 1):

As said before it's very useful to see `tmp` value as Hex:

```
k = 24
k=num >> k=0
k=k & 0xFF=0
tmp = 0
k = 16
k=num >> k=213
k=k & 0xFF=213 // d5
tmp = d500
k = 8
k=num >> k=54773
k=k & 0xFF=245  // f5
tmp = f5d500
k = 0
k=num >> k=14022014
k=k & 0xFF=126  // obviously 7e
tmp = 7ef5d500
t = 2130040064
```

Your code fills `tmp` as flipped `no` value:

```
printf("t = %x, no = %x\n", t, no);
t = 7ef5d500,
no = d5f57e
```

Comment: You should probably mention the byte ordering is little endian. but this should suffice.